# Using Rails RSpec and Capybara and Selenium how can I test to make sure a modal is being displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have a necessary modal that displays when a user has not yet excepted the Terms of Service for a site. I need to test to make sure the bootstrap modal is being displayed after looking through a lot of documentation I am still lost with how to perform this.

```
# application.html.haml
.container-fluid
  - if user_has_not_accepted_terms?
    = render 'parts/terms_modal'
```

my modal

```
.modal#terms_modal{'tabindex': "-1", role: "dialog", 'data- 
    keyboard':false, 'data-backdrop': "static"}
  .modal-dialog{role: "document"}
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %h5.modal-title
          Our Terms of Service have changed
      .modal-body
        %p
          Please take a minute and review our updated BLAH
      .modal-footer
        = link_to 'Accept Terms of Service', accept_terms_user_profile_path(current_user.id, current_user), method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-primary mx-auto'
```

Js making sure that modal opens on page load

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ->
  $('#terms_modal').modal('show')
)

$(document).on('page:load', ->
  $('#terms_modal').modal('show')
)
```

I know the user I am testing against has not yet accepted the terms and the conditional returns true, also when I run call save_and_open_page in my test I get back the html with the modal in it

so far I have tried testing like

```
# accepting_terms_spec.rb
...
scenario 'user can accept terms of service', js: true do
  ... #user sign in and visit '/'

  within('.modal#terms_modal) do
    click_on('Accept Terms of Service')
  end

  expect(page).to have_content('Success')
end
```

I get the return from the test the states the .modal is not visible.

Comment: What driver config are you using with Capybara? If you are actually using Selenium for this test you should just be able to watch the browser and see if the bootstrap modal is actually opening.

Comment: Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome

Comment: Ok, you haven’t tagged the test with `js: true` - is that test actually using Selenium (browser opening)??

Comment: Yes the browser opens and even with scenario 'can do', js: true {} I still get the same result, Also to note when I run rails server I do see the modal

Comment: But when you watch the test run in the browser do you see the modal?

Comment: No, in the test env window it does not appear but is being displayed on save_and_open_page, so it is there but the js or css is not working i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the modal isn't opening in the browser Capybara is correctly failing the test.

Most likely an error in one of your JS files is causing the issue.  The biggest difference between the test and dev environments is that in the test (and production) environment all your JS assets are concatenated into one file.  This allows an error in one to prevent JS in other files from being processed. In the dev environment this doesn't happen because each file is served separately.  Check your browsers developer console for JS errors and fix them and the error will probably go away.

A less likely possibility is that your asset pipeline has hung and is no longer combining new JS changes into the files served in test mode.  You should be able to force a recompile with `rails assets:precompile` although that may still not pick up future changes to your assets depending on exactly what's causing the hang. In that case doing `rails assets:clobber` will usually reset the pipeline to working properly (may need to do `RAILS_ENV=test rails assets:clobber/precompile` to ensure the correct things get cleared/built depending on your exact setup)

Comment: Unfortunately the only return/error  I get from the chrome console is a deprecation warning from selenium. but nothing from my code...

Comment: @CoreyGibson so if it works in dev mode, doesn’t work in test mode, and there really aren’t any JS errors then  I can only think of 2 other possibilities - 1. Your asset pipeline is hung - clobber your precompiled assets to trigger new, or 2. Your user isn’t actually logging in because you’re not waiting for the login to complete before visiting a new url - that should be obvious from watching the test run though

Comment: Running rails assests:precompile worked! wanna through that up as an answer?

Comment: @CoreyGibson Updated answer to include pipeline info

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Shouldn't it be rake assets:precompile?  This solved a problem I've been having for months.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @EricM `rake assets:precompile` will also work currently, however in recent versions of Rails all of the normal `rake ...` commands used with Rails apps were were moved to work under `rails ...` and the `rake ...` versions will eventually go away.